# MVVM pattern : updating Fragment when entrypoint is a Service

Tags: android, service, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a FirebaseMessagingService which when receiving a new Message should make a network call to retrieve some data to show in a Fragment.

To do so I implemented a MVVM pattern, resulting in a Fragment, a ViewModel and a Repository.
Right now I am directly calling the Repository from within the Service to retrieve the needed data. Unfortunately because it's not the ViewModel doing the call the ViewModel's data (observable) is not being updated, thus the Fragment too.

I know I should not pass a reference to a ViewModel, especially not from a service.
So my question is : how do I update the data in the ViewModel if the Repository is not called from that ViewModel ?

So my entrypoint is the service, but the end result should be that my fragment is being updated with fresh data !

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is not recommended to call a ViewModel from a Service directly! But here is another **BAD** solution you can use; you can use Message Bus to communicate between that service and your ViewModel or Fragment; when your Service receives a new message, it can publish an event on the message bus indicating that new data is available. The ViewModel can then subscribe to this event and fetch the data from the Repository when the event is received. Once the data is fetched, the ViewModel can update its observable data, triggering the Fragment to update.

Other than that, you can broadcast a message from the service and register a broadcast receiver in your fragment. When you get the broadcast, you can then ask the viewModel to update and fetch the data!

Comment: the last option, broadcasts, is the implementation we have been using the last 8 years but I was wondering how that would "fit" in the "modern" MVVM pattern. Maybe it has been superceeded by other patterns ? When you mention the service bus is this some kind of 3rd party library like EventBus or is it built into Android and I can't seem to find it :P

Comment: Yeah, it is 3rd party Library like EventBus, but currently, The Broadcast pattern still applies in the Android world, it isn't left behind yet!